# error in show data by date wise in grid

Tags: c#

i have tried to show a data by date wise but i didn't get the answer exactly, please help me..

```
public void gettoday()
    {
        con.Open();
        {
            string strview = @"select MRNO,MaterialCode,Description,Specification,
                              Category as Cat,Source as Sor,Population as Pop, StockInStores as Stock, MRRating as Rating,PreparedBy,PreparedDate,CheckedBy,CheckedDate,ApprovedBy,ApprovedDate  
                         from tbl_KKSMaterialRaise 
                         where PreparedDate between (getdate()-1) and (getdate()+1)";
            SqlCommand cd = new SqlCommand(strview, con);
            SqlDataReader reader = cd.ExecuteReader();

            GridView1.DataSource = reader;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
        con.Close();


    }
```

Comment: What is the error? What did you expect?

Comment: there is no error in that frien. i want to show the data from db to by date wise into grid view(ex: if i'd strored a data today, then it'll show tomorrow under the heading of yesterday, or today, like wise week, month, etc

Answer (score 1):

Your `SQL` query seems to be incorrect. So you want to select records between yesterday and tomorrow.

Then this should work (assuming `SQL-Server` since you use [`GetDate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188383)):

```
WHERE PreparedDate BETWEEN DateAdd(d,-1,GetDate()) AND DateAdd(d,+1,GetDate())
```

- [`DATEADD (Transact-SQL)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx)

**Edit**: Apart from that you should always use `using-statement`( for any object implementing `IDisposable`) to ensure that a connection gets closed even in case of an exception:

```
const string strview = @"select MRNO,MaterialCode,Description,Specification, Category as Cat,Source as Sor,Population as Pop, StockInStores as Stock, MRRating as Rating,PreparedBy,PreparedDate,CheckedBy,CheckedDate,ApprovedBy,ApprovedDate  
                         FROM tbl_KKSMaterialRaise 
                         WHERE PreparedDate BETWEEN DateAdd(d,-1,GetDate()) AND DateAdd(d,+1,GetDate())";
// don't use global connection objects
using(var con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
using(var cmd = new SqlCommand(strview, con))
{
    con.Open();
    GridView1.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: Now also not getting the answer, its simply shows blank space

Comment: @user1455232: Have you debugged the code? Have you checked if the sql works in SQL-Server Management Studio and what it returns?